# while building apk showing APP not installed error in android apk

Tags: android, apk, android-build

I have generated a signed apk and given to client.Next time when i build apk using same signed apk .While installing it is showing as App not installed.Someone please tell me why is it so

Please find my gradle code.The version code was 1 and version name was 1.1 for previous build

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.abc.test"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
 }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0'
implementation 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.0.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
implementation 'com.github.mabbas007:TagsEditText:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
implementation 'com.kbeanie:multipicker:1.1.31@aar'
implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.27') { transitive = true }
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.7.4'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.27'
implementation 'it.michelelacorte.elasticprogressbar:library:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:6.2.12'
implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.7'
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
implementation 'com.evrencoskun.library:tableview:0.8.8'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2-native'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.chinalwb:are:0.1.7'
implementation 'com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: have you tried to sign it?

Comment: Check keystore, package name, version code of old and new apk. Keystore and package name should be same. Version code of new apk should be greater than old apk.

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier means?

Comment: @PrashantSable keystore is correct packagename we are not changing anywhere rt??Version code is increased in build.gradle

Comment: Can you post build.gradle of old and new apk? From that we can check what is going wrong.

Comment: @PrashantSable the entire file??

Comment: try to uninstall previously installed app and install it again !

Comment: check this please https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/generate-signed-apk-android-studio.html

Comment: @VishalThakkar by uninstalling it is working fine .I want it without uninstalling

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier This is how i did it

Comment: then i suggest to post your gradle code

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons why it may be occured:

1. Previous version code is less than the current. Try to increase it or/and check also version name in app info screen on device
2. The signatures don't match each other. Be careful with their data
3. Turn off google play protect. May be the problem is somewhere in google services

Comment: Tried all these

Comment: Try to extract apk with ApkExtractor in Google Play and check signature imprint. Try to logout with google account, why not?

Comment: I cant ask the client to do the same

Comment: There are no way to achieve result here without reverse engineering IMHO. Also there are not many who knows how google services can prevent app install in fact